# GCM User Notifications 404

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to create a notification key to use the User Notification feature in GCM. Sending a POST request to,
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification

with headers,

- content-type: "application/json"
- "project_id": {projectID}
- "Authorization", "key={API_KEY}"

and the body is a json string for user create,
{ 
   "operation": "create",
   "notification_key_name": "appUser-Test",
   "registration_ids": ["{regId1}", "{regId2}"]
}

But, this returns a 404 no matter what. Any ideas?

Comment: For pushing message to GCM. Send your POST request to following domain https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they removed that page. You get

> Not Found
>   Error 404

even if you just follow the [link](https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification).

Perhaps it a temporary thing.

Comment: It may not work even normally if you visit the url. The endpoint probably only supports POST requests.